# remove rows from one table, where a field in a column matches that of same column in different table

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Hi I have two dataframes (called table1 and table2 respectively):

```
ID    MONTH
--    -----

1     Jan  
2     May
3     May          
4     Jan


ID     TEST1   GNDR  
--     -----   ----   

1      90      M  
2      80      M  
3      70      F
```

where I want to remove from table1 any row where the ID matches the ID in table2, so that I am left with:

```
ID    MONTH
--    -----   

4     Jan
```

I just want to say where ID from table2 matches ID in table1, remove all rows relating to those IDs.

I can use the merge() function to obtain the rows where ID is common using

```
merge(table1,table2,by="ID")
```

and store the results in a dataframe, but I do not know how to delete the rows from table1 based on the result of the merge command.

Any help would be great.

Comment: try `table1[!table1$ID %in% table2$ID,]`

Comment: And have a look [here](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) or at some other tutorial of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%in%`

```
df1[!df1$ID %in% df2$ID,]
#  ID MONTH
#4  4   Jan
```